# Circular progress bar restarts when notifydatasetchaged called on RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview

I've one plank in my recyclerView in which there is one `circular progressbar`. it runs continuously. now i need to change other data of that plank so i'm using `notifydatasetchaged` . It works fine and changes data but it also restarts animation of that progressbar also. because changes are frequent , it looks like progressbar is lagging everytime. how to solve it?

Comment: DO NOT USE NOTIFYDATSET, instead use notifyitemchnaged

Comment: I need to update data of same row. Same thing will happen.

Comment: try using RXJava and data binding then,then ur progressbar wont b refreshed